# Search combo box with "All" or "Any" option

Tags: sql, combobox

In MS Acccess I have a column in my table that uses a drop down menu to select the value for the field, with six possible options. I am trying to make the same drop down menu/combo box in my form so that when a particular option from the list is selected it will filter my search query. I've made it to that point and works without a problem here.

However I want to have an option in the combo box that will say "Any" or "All" which will behave in a way that all records will be shown. Like when the combo box is initially blank when nothing is selected and the query shows all the records.

I have researched on the internet a few ways to do this, but I cannot get it to work properly.

I have added the UNION to my `RowSource` query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT [testtable].[colourtype] 
FROM   [testtable] 
UNION 
SELECT "any" 
FROM   [testtable];
```

And I added this to my `AfterUpdate` event:

```
If Me.ColourT = "Any" Then
  strFilter = "*"
End If
```

What this does strangely is: it made my combo box list with blank values, there are six blank spaces (white) and no text.

EDIT:
This is the code I have in my criteria for the query:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![ColourT] & "*"
```

Comment: Can you show us all the code after you select an item from the ComboBox? The basic idea would be to set the filter criteria after you select a value. If the selected value is "Any" or whatever else would reset the criteria, then you remove the filter

Comment: Without `UNION`, are you getting the colour types in your ComboBox?

Comment: @ravindraGullapalli Yes without the 'UNION' it shows the values in the combo box and can select them to filter the query.

Comment: @Jeff I've added the code that I have used in the criteria for the query. I guess that needs to be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made it worked based on the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650130/values-not-showing-in-access-form-combo-box)

Constructed Query like this

```
SELECT [id], [colourtype] 
FROM   [testtable] 
UNION 
SELECT 0, "any" 
FROM   [testtable];
```

and set this query as **Row source** of combo box.

In **control source** property, choose `colourtype`.

Now combo box shows values. Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I am getting it straight away without any brackets.

Comment: I have created the combo box from scratch, this is the original query I have right now: `SELECT [testtable].ID, [testtable].[colourtype]
FROM [testtable]
ORDER BY [testtable].[colourtype];`

Comment: I have added the UNION like in your example, and I have got this error when trying to open the combo box list: "The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match"

Comment: I removed the `[testable].ID` from the query and now I'm back to the same problem as I originally described... blank values in the combo box.

Comment: I had changed the query. Have a look at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43996/discussion-between-user3124052-and-ravindra-gullapalli)

Comment: Thanks, that shows all the values however I had to remove the `colourtype` from control source. Now it still doesn't filter the query when selecting a particular value. I'm guessing my criteria in the query is wrong. I have tried using the LIKE and without it and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: check which value you are getting in `[Forms]![Search]![ColourT]`

Comment: With this I'm getting all records regardless which value I choose in the combo box